# How to debug a Java maven spring-boot app in vs code?

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, visual-studio-code

I was able to debug a simple Java hello world. The first step was to "compile" with `javac -g`. I looked up how I would acomplish the same with maven and found http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/examples/run-debug.html, but those instructions are for running the application and wait for a debugger to connect.

I also tried to use `target/classes` for `classpath` in  `launch.json`. The debugger complains that it cannot find a file in the root directory `/`, but it runs. Althought the debugger is running, the application is not responding to HTTP requests.

Is there a `mvn` command to compile the application with `javac -g` and produce a `.class` the debugger is able to run successfully?

Answer (score 20):

You will only be able to remote debug with vs code, so a simple command will be `mvnDebug spring-boot:run`, which will do the same thing as `mvn spring-boot:run` but add these options:

```
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=y
```

Then you can attach from vs code, a sample launch.json looks like:

```
{
 "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [

    {
      "type": "java",
      "name": "Debug (Launch)",
      "request": "launch",
      "mainClass": "",
      "args": ""
    },
    {
      "type": "java",
      "name": "Debug (Attach)",
      "request": "attach",
      "hostName": "localhost",
      "port": 8000
    }
  ] 
}
```

and you can select `Debug(Attach)` from the debug panel to run.

Comment: PS: If you are using Java 1.8+ use these flags instead `mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments="agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8000"` as answered here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-java-debug/issues/300

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you've installed the *collection package* [Java Extension Pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-pack) by Microsoft **debugging Maven Spring Boot applications seems to work right-out-of-the-box**.

Launch `code` **from the project's root directory** and "Start Debugging".  *There are multiple ways to launch the debbugger -- the most straightforward is to just hit `F5` and, if it asks, select `Java`.*

Under nominal conditions this triggers the following steps:

1. Your application is compiled into class files
2. It finds and launches your application's `main` function -- which should include `SpringApplication.run()`
3. The application runs (with breakpoints enabled) and log output is sent to the TERMINAL panel.

Related links:

- https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-spring-boot
- [How can I fix build failed, do you want to continue? in vscode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50454523)

Comment: TODO: Environment variables

Comment: Debug with environment variables: `( export spring_profiles_active=local ; code . )`

Comment: It may be necessary to have open a java file in the current edit window.  If this isn't working, try opening the file with the application's `main()`.