# How can I fix "Build failed, do you want to continue?" in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: java, debugging, visual-studio-code

I am trying to debug Java code which is only hello world program.

```
public class Hello
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      System.out.println("hello world");
   }
}
```

The code above has no error. But Visual Studio Code keeps warning this message to me even though the code has no error. But every time when I click **Proceed**, Visual Studio Code can debug Java code successfully.

[image]

I don't really know which build is failed.

And this is my launch.json for Java debugger. Did I set it up correctly?

```
{
    "type": "java",
    "name": "Java",
    "request": "launch",
    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
    "console": "integratedTerminal",
    "stopOnEntry": false,
    "mainClass": "Hello",
    "args": ""
},
```

In the `mainClass`, I can just use `"mainClass": "Hello"` as usual to debug Java code after saving the file as `Hello.java`, and use `javac Hello.java` to build `Hello.class`.

I really don't know which build is failed or if it is a bug in Java debugger.

Could you please help me fix this problem?

Comment: Did you solve the problem ? How ?

Comment: Hi, I have solved the problem. There are 2 ways to solve. First, use Maven. Second, press Ctrl + Shift + P, and you type Java in it. You will see create Java project. Both ways will give you classpath file which is the requirement. Also, you must have Java Extension from Microsoft installed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I fix build failed, do you want to continue? in vscode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50454523/how-can-i-fix-build-failed-do-you-want-to-continue-in-vscode)

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the Java Language Server workspace directory. Here's where they are generally found depending on your OS.

Windows

> %APPDATA%\Code[ - Variant]\User\workspaceStorage\

MacOS

> $HOME/Library/Application Support/Code[Variant]/User/workspaceStorage/

Linux

> $HOME/.config/Code[Variant]/User/workspaceStorage/

You can find more information regarding cleaning your workplace here. Cleaning [vscode java workplace](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/wiki/Troubleshooting#clean-the-workspace-directory)

Comment: Thank you for sharing the solution. I have tried what you said, but the problem just disappeared for a moment, and then there is the same problem again. It seems this is only temporary solution. If you have another way, please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug of vs code.

delete the file in `/Users/airren/Library/Application Support/Code/User/workspaceStorage` can fix this problem, but you may be lost your workspace.

Comment: windows : `C:\Users\<myuser>\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\workspaceStorage`