# configure cmake target debug in VSCode with other targets

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, debugging

I need to configure and debug in VSCdoe some app written in C++, there are a lot of guidance with cpptools and cmaketools in vscode but I could not find one case :

how to add to launch json a steps to prepare the environment.
I need to run few other processes (which are actually are cmake targets of my project too) before run a current target to debug

any idea - is it really possible in vscode and how?

Comment: There should be a `"preLaunchTask"` parameter in `launch.json`, or something similarly named (I'm using it with a non-stock debugging plugin). Put a name of a task from `tasks.json` there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How run build task automatically before debugging in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57891050/how-run-build-task-automatically-before-debugging-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: no , the building target before debug is not a problem. my cmake project contains ~10 targets , and couple of them should be ran before all any targets debuging because these two targets serves some network requests from others. so I need to debug current cmake target in vscode with a guarantee that some two targets are running and these are ready to reply for valid debugging. something like "pre-launch tasks" where I can add targets would solve the problem. but I'm not sure

Comment: first comment is more valid for me but  it relates to tasks.json and I'm not using tasks.json as cmake-tools extension does all building work under the hood, so I'm now reading the doc to understand how to use this option in my case